# parse date time from string in spotfire

Tags: date, expression, visualization, spotfire

one column in my csv file is a date that is read as a string and it follows this pattern : 2018-09-19 10:27:28.409Z. I am struggling to convert the column from string to date.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion options in spotfire didn't allow me to change the column type. however, I found the solution, at the moment of importing the data set (file) you need to specify the type (date time) and magically spotfire manages the conversion.